# Two docker containers with Traefik on one host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik, docker-container

I'm trying to set up a server on my raspberry pi to run Nextcloud and Firefly III with traefik as a reverse proxy. I'm using docker-compose and Portainer is working fine with https (included in the code for testing), but I cannot get Nextcloud or Firefly to run at all. When I use the official documentation for Firefly I can get it to run and when I use NextcloudPi in itself I can also get that to run, but I cannot get both of them to work at the same time. FF is giving a 403 Forbidden "You don't have permission to access / on this server." error while Nextcloud is giving a "Bad Gateway" error. I'd be grateful for any help I can get regarding this as I've already read through as many sites as possible and I don't what else to do.

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.2"

services:
  # Reverse Proxy and Let's Encrypt
  traefik:
    container_name: traefik
    image: traefik:alpine
    restart: always
    networks:
      - srv
      - firefly_iii_net
      - proxy-tier
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - /opt/traefik/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /opt/traefik/acme.json:/acme.json

  # Portainer
  portainer:
    container_name: portainer
    image: portainer/portainer
    restart: always
    networks:
      - srv
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /opt/portainer:/data
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:port.skdjfgsl.club"

  db:
    image: postgres:alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=
      - POSTGRES_DB=nextcloud
      - POSTGRES_USER=nextcloud

  app:
    image: nextcloud:fpm-alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - nextcloud:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_HOST=db
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=
      - POSTGRES_DB=nextcloud
      - POSTGRES_USER=nextcloud
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - proxy-tier
    expose:
      - 80
      - 443
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:nc.skdjfgsl.club"

  firefly_iii_app: 
    environment: 
      - FF_DB_HOST=firefly_iii_db
      - FF_DB_NAME=firefly
      - FF_DB_USER=firefly
      - FF_DB_PASSWORD=firefly
      - FF_APP_KEY=S0m3R@nd0mStr1ngOf32Ch@rsEx@ctly
      - FF_APP_ENV=local
      - FF_DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
      - TZ=Europe/Amsterdam
      - APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
      - TRUSTED_PROXIES=**
    image: jc5x/firefly-iii
    links: 
      - firefly_iii_db
    networks: 
      - firefly_iii_net
    volumes: 
      - 
        source: firefly_iii_export
        target: /var/www/firefly-iii/storage/export
        type: volume
      - 
        source: firefly_iii_upload
        target: /var/www/firefly-iii/storage/upload
        type: volume
    expose:
      - 80
      - 443
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:ff.skdjfgsl.club"
      - traefik.port=443

  firefly_iii_db: 
    environment: 
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=firefly
      - POSTGRES_USER=firefly
    image: "postgres:10"
    networks: 
      - firefly_iii_net
    volumes: 
      - "firefly_iii_db:/var/lib/postgresql/data"

networks:
  srv:
  firefly_iii_net: 
    driver: bridge
  proxy-tier:

volumes:
  db:
  nextcloud:
  firefly_iii_db: ~
  firefly_iii_export: ~
  firefly_iii_upload: ~
```

This is my traefik.toml:

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

logLevel = "DEBUG"

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
    address = ":80"
      [entryPoints.http.redirect]
        entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
    address = ":443"
      [entryPoints.https.tls]

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "mydomain.com"
exposedByDefault = false
watch = true

[acme]
email = "email@mydomain.com"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onHostRule = true
  [acme.httpChallenge]
  entryPoint = "http"
```

Answer (score 0):

To go to port 443 (https) you need to adjust the protocol used by traefik to talk to the container with the following label:

```
- traefik.protocol=https
```

Bad gateway can mean traefik is trying to connect to the wrong port, wrong IP, or traefik and the container are not deployed to a common network. You can fix the first two by specifying a port and network name:

```
- traefik.port=80
- traefik.docker.network=project_proxy-tier
```

Where project is the name of your compose project (use `docker network ls` to see the external name of your networks).